# Error when accessing drive in Google Colab using a GCP Backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-compute-engine, google-colaboratory

When I run this command in Google Colab with Compute Engine Backend

```
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

I am getting this error "KeyError: 'CLOUDSDK_CONFIG' "

I have read somewhere that Google Colab does not support drive integration with GCP Backend. is that true? if yes then what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that is true, since I am getting the same error. A good alternative is [google-drive-ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse), which performs the same function, allowing you to mount your Google Drive as a folder. Install google-drive-ocamlfuse on your VM, then perform the steps described in [Headless Usage & Authorization](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Headless-Usage-&-Authorization).

Comment: @Lokesh Yes, it works fairly well, although you have to remember that if you are uploading a big file, it has to duplicate that file into cache first, and then upload it; so make sure you have at least double the space of any file you want to upload. That isn't a new thing, as it happens in Google Colab as well, however.

Comment: Great, well I don't have the use case now but I hope it helps someone else. Thanks!